# Accessing backend services on Docker Container from React front end requires IP, rather than localhost

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, camunda

We have a multi-containerized application(docker-compose) running on our Docker Desktop. There is one Camunda BPM backend service running on a container   which we are trying to access from our front end application based on React running on other container. The issue we are facing is that , when are trying to access Camunda BPM service through the exposed port using "localhost" its not working. But things work when we use local IP on the host machine. What it makes different between localhost and local IP while accessing a service on back end from a front end REACT application?

Comment: Please post your docker-compose.yml so we can see the port setup

Answer (score 0):

When two services (containers) are running within docker-compose they are using a dedicated network. Thus, the services can communicate by their **names** and not `localhost`.

If you call your camunda's service `camunda` and it is listening on port 8080 - the react service can access it via http://camunda:8080

Comment: Be careful!  A React application typically runs in a browser, which is outside Docker space; it _can't_ use the Docker-internal hostnames or IP addresses, and instead needs to use the host's (or VM's) DNS name or IP address and the container's published port.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze! I thought that they are communicating via backend

Comment: @ItayB , David Maze - Thanks for you comments. Yes, that is right - React is communicating via client side/browser - so cant use internal service name. But localhost with exposed port should work, right? Thats is not happening , rather I am forced to use IP - which  i need to avoid

Comment: how about host.docker.internal

Comment: How are u running Camunda? With host 0.0.0.0? Can you share the command?

Comment: @ItayB  In Docker, where  we use a Java Springboot app to integrate Camunda BPM with Keycloak IDMS. Entrypoint point on docker file look like this ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/camunda-bpm-identity-keycloak-examples-sso-kubernetes.jar"]

Comment: so in the Springboot, is there something like `builder.addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")`? (and not specific interface)

Comment: @ItayB - No. we dont have any reference like this.